# Entity framework, is it possible to use substract in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 database fields and there is need to filter results based on those values.

As an example customers max storage places and storage places in use. To determine if someone is using more space I would like to make like this.

```
var temp = db.Storege.Where(o => (o.max_storage_places - o.places_in_use) < 0).ToList()
```

But this is not working. Is this possible or should I use different approach?

EDIT:

Database is MySQL and it is used trough Entity Framework. The datatype for both fields are INT values in database.

I tested that following version is working which was suggested

```
var temp = db.Storege.Where(o => o.max_storage_places < o.places_in_use).ToList()
```

ROOT CAUSE:

I was investigating this problem more deeply and found out that this is MySQL related issue. The fields were for some reason "Unsigned INT" so for database didn't understand the negative values in calculation.

Both cases will work

Comment: what is the data type of this `max_storage_palces` ?

Comment: Why you think that this is not working?

Comment: What happens when it "is not working"? What are the datatypes (both DB and .NET)? Why not `o.max_storage_palces < o.places_in_use`? Are you sure that should be `palces` and not `places`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to subtract one value from another.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Query doesn't return any results.

Comment: If @Sampath's answer still doesn't return any results, maybe the list doesn't have items where the places in use exceed the limit?

Comment: @user4845680: Then no matching results are found.  The database isn't lying to you.  The query you've built doesn't match any of the data present.

Comment: Added roor cause description to this case. More deeper investigation showed that it was caused by unsigned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can do it.But you have to use `ToList()` to fetch the records from the database.

```
var temp = db.Storege.Where(o => (o.max_storage_palces - o.places_in_use) < 0).ToList();
```

OR

```
var temp = db.Storege.Where(o => (o.max_storage_palces < o.places_in_use ).ToList();
```